# How to display the logcat of android emulator on travis-ci?

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration, android-logcat, travis-ci

I got an Android project on GitHub that uses Travis-ci for continuous integration.

[Builds currently fail](https://travis-ci.org/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android) and I need to display the logcat of the emulator to find more details about the problem that occurs during the automated build.

I tried to add both :

```
after_failure:
  - adb logcat 

after_script:
  - adb logcat
```

But both commands never get executed.

Maybe this is due to travis-ci java project builds that execute a `mvn install` command before the real script is executed and both commands don't get executed... I am really stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already dont need it but I'll try to answer the question.

You need add the `--all` flag otherwise these packages were not available.

Google deprecated the `-p --obsolete` flag and only suggested (newer) packages are available without `-a --all` flag.

See [missing build-tools - line 56](https://travis-ci.org/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android/jobs/18750302#L56)

```
 echo "y" | android update sdk --filter platform-tools,build-tools-17.0.0,android-16,extra-android-support,$ANDROID_SDKS --no-ui --force > /dev/null
Error: Missing platform-tools
Error: Missing platform-tools
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-17.0.0'
```

Currently latest platform-tools are suggested always without `--all` flag but:

```
$ ./android update sdk -u -t build-tools-17.0.0
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-17.0.0'
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
$ ./android update sdk -a -u -t build-tools-17.0.0
Packages selected for install:
- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
```

Probably the lack of build-tools and android-17 platform are the cause of [Properties file not found.](https://travis-ci.org/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android/jobs/18750302#L399)

And I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581057) a work around for travis-lint, I don't use it.

---

This is the current work around I use for logs, needs be improved but works, `-e` for emulator. You need custom your `MOD_NAME`.

> ```
> # adb -e: direct an adb command to the only running emulator. Return an error if more than one.
>
> before_script:   
>   # - echo 'LOGCAT'   
>   # Check logcat debug output: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html
>   # Check debugging log: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html
>   # Comment the lines belows to debug output and redirect it to a file. Custom tags for your app.
>   - adb -e logcat *:W | tee logcat.log > /dev/null 2>&1 &
>
> after_failure:
>   # - echo 'FAILURE'
>   # Check apt configuration: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#apt-configuration
>   # Comment out the lines below to show log about tests with app name customized on exports section.
>   - sudo apt-get install -qq lynx
>   - export MOD_NAME=yourappmodulename
>   - export LOG_DIR=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${MOD_NAME}/build/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/
>   - lynx --dump ${LOG_DIR}com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.html > myConnectedDevice.log
>   - lynx --dump ${LOG_DIR}com.android.builder.testing.html > myTesting.log
>   - for file in *.log; do echo "$file"; echo "====================="; cat "$file"; done || true
>
> after_script:
>   # Uncomment the line below to kill adb and show logcat output.
>   - echo " LOGCAT "; echo "========"; cat logcat.log; pkill -KILL -f adb
> ```

I'm looking for a pre-installed alternative to `lynx` because `sudo` is not available using container-based infrastructure and `cat` is really for concatenate files, if anyone knows to improve it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional attempts, I can get logcat via either one  :

```
 #build 25
 #run all tests 
  - mvn clean install -DskipTests=false
 #build 26
  - adb logcat &
```

in before_install travis phase.

I by pass the mvn install -DskipTests=true of Travis. Nevertheless I couldn't get any way to get the logcat during a regular build. Any idea ?