# travis-lint: why does it complain about java language field

Tags: travis-ci

I have this dead simple [.travis.yml](https://github.com/emeraldjava/emeraldjava/blob/master/.travis.yml) for a java project. When i run 'travis-lint' against the file is complains

```
[17:24:23@emeraldjava]$ travis-lint
/Users/pauloconnell/projects/emeraldjava/.travis.yml has issues:
Found an issue with the `language:` key:
Language must be valid
```

Any ideas?

My [build](https://travis-ci.org/emeraldjava/emeraldjava) actually works once deployed out.

Comment: Are you using the web linter?

Comment: @joshua-anderson Not sure what a web linter is. This is just a plain old terminal and locally installed travis-lint.

Comment: OK. This is problaby a bug with the linter. I'll take a look.

Comment: I have the same issue with "language: android"

Comment: Same issue here, Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.3p374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the problem is resolved with the command line tool, and as @joshua-anderson proposed, use the web linter http://lint.travis-ci.org/.

Simply copy/paste your `.travis.yml` file's content their (or use your github repository directly like `emeraldjava/emeraldjava`) and hit validate.